# C# multithreaded incrementation

Tags: c#, multithreading, increment

I'm trying to make an application (and learn C# along the way) that basically counts. The faster the better.

That's why initially I was thinking about multiple threads. However, as I see it, it wouldn't be possible, because the whole point of multithreading is to run code in parallel at the same time, right?

So, can I use multiple threads? Or any general tips as to make it increment faster?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question as it stands is very vague. You are to explain in greater detail, what you need. And definitely you should show here, what you've already tried.

Comment: If you're just adding And you're new... I would not start with multithreading

Comment: Incrementing is not a good choice for learning about parallelization. Choose an "embarrassingly parallelizable" CPU-bound problem: that is, a problem where you can split the problem up into many pieces and solve each sub-problem independently, and a problem where the CPU is going to be majorly stressed. For example, the problem "compute a picture of the Mandelbrot set" can be divided up as fine as you like; you can do half the image on each of two threads, or a third of the image on each of three threads, and so on. The number of threads should be equal to the number of idle processors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to partition the number range. E.g., instead of incrementing from 0 to 999'999 in one thread, let four threads increment from 0 to 249'999, from 250'000 to 499'999, from 500'000 to 749'999 and from 750'000 to 999'999 respectively.

And have a look at [Task Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx).

Do not make the error to create one million tasks that increment once! The multitasking overhead would actually slow down the process considerably. You can actually only make a gain in speed, if every task has to perform a substantial amount of work.

Comment: Yes, the domain of work needs to be divided into ranges (bins), then parallel processing can help out.

Comment: This sounds very interesting. I haven't thought of it that way. Splitting it up into ranges sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For the best performance, for simple incrementing of a single variable, I would use the often overlooked [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) class.

```
private long SingleVariable = 0;
public void MultiThreadedMethod()
{
   Interlocked.Increment(SingleVariable);
}
```

Although there would be no perceived benefit from multi-threading, performance wise in this simple example, as I would expect the cache (cache coherence network) bandwidth to be the bottleneck in such a case.

However, such a pattern is often useful in the multi-threaded world, where multiple threads may be completing a Unit of Work, and then incrementing a central counter to track the total progress across the threads. The alternative to interlocked, would be to use a Monitor.Enter (or lock keyword in C#), which would be relatively slower.